# connect sql developer on windows to a db on VM Oracle Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i connect using sql developer on VM Oracle Linux to my db oracle, that is on the VM too. The setting is that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAk60.jpg)

i try to connect the db using sql developer on windows with the same settings but it not work. What i have to do?

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error? Are you connecting to a VM?

Comment: i can't create the connection with sql developer on windows using the same settings that i use on sqldeveloper on the VM. The error is Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

Comment: Well, from the error, the SID is wrong. Do you have tnsnames.ora on your machine? Does it have that SID?